# Push notification for android

Tags: android, push-notification

I am going to implement push notification on my app which is on Android platform. The app has 2 different types namely Company and Member. How am I going to differentiate the notification sent whether it is for the Company or for the Member? I need to do that because I want to display different notification for Company and for Member. TQ in advance.

Comment: Are You building Two Apps and requires a single push of the notification or the same apps for both the company and members

Comment: It is the same app for company and members

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just  distinguish  device's  registration_id  when you  record  them into your database  by certain column,

and select certain registration_ids  when you send push .

Comment: but the company and the member are in the same app